# Call Unit Of Work dependable Business Service in Windows Service in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture

I use .NET Core 3.1 and I have the following projects separations:

[image]

And I use UnitOfWork (located in DataAccessLayer) and Business Services for business logic which depends on the UnitOfWork. So far everything is standard. I register Unit of Work and the Services in API Startup.cs, then inject the UnitOfWork interface in every BusinessService and use it freely :)

```
public class ExampleBusinessService
{

  private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
  private IUsersService _userService;
  public ExampleBusinessService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUsersService userService)
  {
    this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    this._userService = userService;
  }
```

However, now I need to use some of these business services in the windows service project (separate library).

In the previous ASP .NET versions i have created a Factory Class, creating all the services and inside the creating new instance of the UnitOfWork. However I`m not sure how to use CORE patterns to achieve that.

Now assume I need the IUserService from the example in the windows service library, what is the best way to achieve that?

Create manually new UnitOfWork Instace and dispose it at some point? This way the windows service knows about DataAccessLayer and I do no like that.

Or maybe Create some Factory class in the Service Layer which creates its own UnitOfWork class and like this I will have both Core way (in the API) and old school way (when using windows service)??

Comment: Could you please tell me which kind of windows service you have used? As far as I know, asp.net core also contains windows service ,you could refer to this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/) to know how to use it and inject the service.

Comment: using System.ServiceProcess.ServerBase, System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0 in the .NET Framework. Now I intend to migrate to .NET Core